# Why can't I make a second Digest request?

Tags: php, hash

I have read the documentation on rfc7616 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7616), but I am not able to do a second query within one authorization. My understanding is that I have to make a null (empty) request, then get a nonce from the response, count A1 and A2, and then, with the resulting header, make the first request. In subsequent queries, I have to increase the NC and change the URI.

1. I make an empty query.
2. I get a response 401 and nonce.
3. I calculate the response, A1 and A2.
4. I make the first query.
5. I get the response 200
6. I change URI, NC and count new response
7. I get response 401 stale=true

For some reason second query returns me 401 error and stale=true. Can you tell me, am I making a mistake somewhere or is there a problem in the server?

```
    $urlcam = 'http://website.com';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

function request($url, $header) {
    $request_header = array($header);
    $request_header[] = 'Accept: */*';

    $ch = curl_init($GLOBALS['urlcam'].$url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request_header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true
    ]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return ["res" => $response, "info" => $info];
}

function authparse($data) {
    preg_match('/WWW-Authenticate: Digest (.*)/', $data, $matches);
    $auth_header_array = explode(',', $matches[1]);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($auth_header_array as $pair) {
      $vals = explode('=', $pair);
      $result[trim($vals[0])] = trim(trim($vals[1]),'"');
    }
    return $result;
}


$start = date("Y-m-d%20H:i:s", strtotime('18.07.2022 09:00:00'));
$end = date("Y-m-d%20H:i:s", strtotime('18.07.2022 18:00:00'));


##################################################################################
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
# Empty request

$urlCreate = "/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=factory.create";
$resultCreate = request($urlCreate, '');

##################################################################################
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
# First request

$resultCreateParse = authparse($resultCreate['res']);

$realm = $resultCreateParse['realm'];
$qop = $resultCreateParse['qop'];
$opaque = $resultCreateParse['opaque'];
$nonce = $resultCreateParse['nonce'];

$cnonce = "0a4f113b";
$nc = "00000001";

$a1 = md5($username.":".$realm.":".$password);
$a2 = md5("GET:".$urlCreate);
$a3 = md5($a1.':'.$nonce.':'.$nc.':'.$cnonce.':'.$qop.':'.$a2);

$headerCreate = 'Authorization: Digest username="'.$username.'",realm="'.$realm.'",nonce="'.$nonce.'",uri="'.$urlCreate.'",cnonce="'.$cnonce.'",nc='.$nc.',response="'.$a3.'",qop="'.$qop.'",opaque="'.$opaque.'"';

$resultCreate = request("$urlCreate", $headerCreate);


$id = explode('result=',trim($resultCreate['res']))[1];


##################################################################################
##################################################################################
##################################################################################
# Second request
$urlFindFile = "/cgi-bin/mediaFileFind.cgi?action=findFile&condition.Channel=1&condition.StartTime=$start&condition.EndTime=$end&condition.Types[0]=dav&object=$id";

$cnonce = "0a4f113b";
$nc = "00000002";

$a1 = md5($username.":".$realm.":".$password);
$a2 = md5("GET:".$urlFindFile);
$a3 = md5($a1.':'.$nonce.':'.$nc.':'.$cnonce.':'.$qop.':'.$a2);

$headerFindFile = 'Authorization: Digest username="'.$username.'",realm="'.$realm.'",nonce="'.$nonce.'",uri="'.$urlFindFile.'",cnonce="'.$cnonce.'",nc='.$nc.',response="'.$a3.'",qop="'.$qop.'",opaque="'.$opaque.'"';

$resultFindFile = request($urlFindFile, $headerFindFile);
```

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to handle this yourself? You set `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_DIGEST` already, so add `CURLOPT_USERNAME` and `CURLOPT_PASSWORD` with the appropriate values, and be done with it ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for responding to the question. I need to execute 3 queries in one session sequentially: "action=factory.create" then "action=findFile" and at the end "action=findNextFile". If I just pass the login and password in curl parameters, then each request will be like a separate authorization. I really can't figure out if this is a problem with the server I'm connecting to or if I'm making a mistake somewhere? Do you know any service where I can authorize through Digest to check my code?

Comment: _"If I just pass the login and password in curl parameters, then each request will be like a separate authorization."_ - that's how HTTP Auth works anyway; the credentials need to be sent again with every single request.

Comment: @CBroe The problem is that for some reason a server error occurs on new requests. When I contacted the developer, he told me that the reason in new sessions at each request. And if I do Digest, I save one session for three requests.

At the moment, if I execute 2 requests with login and password in Curl option, I will get this result. https://pastebin.com/5ym9UbKn

Comment: What "session"? If you are talking about a cookie-based session - then you should use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE & CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.

Comment: @CBroe the server does not return cookies for me to use later. Regarding your question about sessions: isn't using the same nonce in multiple requests a single session? The first query returns me a 401 error and a nonce, then I do the calculation and run subsequent queries, increasing the NC each time. Why then do I need NC if I have to get a new nonce each time? This is what I understand a session to be. The problem is that after the calculation I get an answer of 200, but when I increase the NC and replace the URI I get a 401 error and stale = true
https://pastebin.com/sE64TjBP

Comment: _"isn't using the same nonce in multiple requests a single session?"_ - I guess technically you could call it that, but I have never heard of any service actually using this to _implement_ a session. Are you _supposed_ to work with some kind of session here? Because I still don't get what the purpose of what you are doing here, is supposed to be in the first place. Normally, to request a Digest Auth protected resource, you would just pass cURL the username and password - and it will handle the rest.

Comment: Can you hit this endpoint with your browser and have it work? If so, it might help to look at the headers exchanged there.

Comment: @CBroe Come on I have an ip camera (Dahua) which has an SD memory card. I want to constantly (every 10 minutes) make backups from it. To get the recordings from the camera I need to make 3 queries in sequence: the first query will create a task and will give an ID, the second query will set the search parameters, and the third query will give the result. The camera supports two types of authorization: Basic and Digest. In Basic authorization I sometimes get an error on the second or third request with the text "ID not found".

Comment: @CBroe Again, the error occurs sometimes: for 100 requests there will be about 20 with errors. I contacted the technical support of the camera, where I was recommended to replace Basic authorization with Digest. They suggested that the error occurs because with Basic authorization each request is taken as a separate session and the camera loses ID, but if I will make requests through Digest authorization, the session will be saved and ID will not be lost.

Comment: @ChrisHaas There httponly. Is there any way to use them? https://telegra.ph/file/0817640a5fa24d13ba756.png

Comment: @k97x, the cookies are HttpOnly, but that's just the basics of a browser without JS. You might want to try using PostMan or similar. Otherwise, I think you have a fairly unique situation and short of experimenting with the real hardware I think I'm at a loss unfortunately.